# Google search results style drop down button

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking for a simple JavaScript or some CSS for a drop down menu, just like the one on Google search results. Small arrow when clicked shows 'Cached', 'Similar' options.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any CSS or even some HTML markup you can show us to work with?

Answer (score 1):

The basic implementation is pretty easy, but you can start from here and make it more nice looking and better UI experience:

```
<div class="button">
    <span class="dropdown-button-text">Dropdown</span>
    <div class="popup">
        Popup content
    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .button { position: relative; display: inline-block; min-width: 100px; }
    .popup { position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; display: none; min-width: 300px; min-height: 50px; border: 1px solid #9F9F9F; }
</style>

<script>
    $("body").delegate(".dropdown-button-text", "click", function () {
        var popup = $(this).parent().children(".popup");
        if (popup.is(":visible")) {
            popup.hide();

        } else {
            popup.show();
        }
    });
</script>
```